# Accessing stream variable in a custom RxJS operator in parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to find a way how to access the stream variable in a custom operator. My effect looks like this:

```
@Effect()
v$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionTypes.Action),
  map((action: ActionType) => action.payload),
  customOperator(
    new ActionCall(<I need to use the stream variable here>),
    ... // some other things not important in this context
  ),
);
```

And the customOperator looks like this:

```
export function customOperator<T>(<function parameters>): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return function (source$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    ... // the stream variable is available here but it's no use to me here
  };
}
```

I've tried assigning the stream variable into a class variable inside the `tap` operator but it gets undefined that way. This is really driving me crazy.

Comment: Try `customOperator( payload => {...})`

Comment: I can't use it that way because my customOperator expects arguments.

Comment: oh, I see.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Can you put `new ActionCall(...)` inside the custom operator where it has access to the emitted values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for really isn't possible. `customOperator` creates a new stream, but it can't know the values in the stream until after creation time. That's what starts getting passed in after you subscribe.

You can, however, get `customOperator` to hand you the value as it receives it. Just like map, filter, ect - you'll need `customOperator` to take a function as input (it can still take whatever other parameters as well). That function can take the stream value as it's argument and return whatever your `customOperator` needs. That might look like this:

```
@Effect()
v$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionTypes.Action),
  map((action: ActionType) => action.payload),
  customOperator(
    val => new ActionCall(val),
    ... // some other things not important in this context
  ),
);

export function customOperator<T>(func, <other function parameters>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return function (source$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    streamVariable = ... // the stream variable is available here b̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶m̶e̶
    const actionCall = func(streamVariable);
    // Use actionCall however you need.
  };
}
```

Now you've used your stream variable to create a `new ActionCall`. That's about as close as you'll get with RxJS.

Comment: Thank you! I came to this solution already myself but this is exactly the explanation that I needed. This is the correct answer.